# Facebook API - fql_query, Invalid session

Tags: session, facebook

I'm trying to query Facebook with the PHP Library and what I've read it shouldn't required a session key, or rather it shouldn't require one for my case, but my code below gives me the following error: "Session key invalid or no longer valid".

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fql.query
"For example, querying the user table is like calling users.getInfo without a session key -- you can query only on a few fields."

```
$fb = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET);

$query = "SELECT uid,
    name,
    sex,
    pic_square,
    profile_url
    FROM user WHERE name = 'some name' OR username = 'some name'";

$result = $fb->api_client->fql_query($query);
```

Any ideas?

/Thanks

Comment: From my experience you have to have an active user to get any profile data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that policy has changed and you cannot query user table without session.
You can try to query standard_user_info table. Think it doesn't need session.