# curl query to Facebook FQL requires auth?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I used curl to query Facebook's FQL and this happened:

```
> curl 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query' -d "query=SELECT+now()+FROM+user+WHERE+name='Barry Carter';" 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<error_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/ http://api.facebook.com/1.0/facebook.xsd"> 
  <error_code>102</error_code> 
  <error_msg>Session key invalid or no longer valid</error_msg> 
  <request_args list="true"> 
    <arg> 
      <key>method</key> 
      <value>fql.query</value> 
    </arg> 
    <arg> 
      <key>query</key> 
      <value>SELECT now() FROM user WHERE name='Barry Carter';</value> 
    </arg> 
  </request_args> 
</error_response>
```

Do I need to authenticate even to find users? On the website, you can 
do that sans authentication?

If I do need authentication, how do I get it? I've read 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication but do I need all 
that for a simple curl call? If so, what should I do to get an auth 
token? Do I need to store cookies/etc (using curl's -b and -c flags?).

This question is similar to 
[Facebook API - fql_query, Invalid session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683452/facebook-api-fql-query-invalid-session) 
but I'm using straight curl, not PHP.

I realize the query should be GET, not POST, but I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you'll need to have an auth token for pretty much any query you perform.

It's not that hard to manually acquire one if you're just experimenting. The easiest way to do it manually is to follow the "client-side flow" section of the authentication doc page you linked by navigating to the specified URL in your browser, and use http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as the target URL (it's just a dummy page on facebook.com, so it is guaranteed to let you through), and then grab the access token from the address bar.

Comment: OK, so something like 
"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&response_type=token" 
with YOUR_URL set to http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html? It looks like I still need a YOUR_APP_ID to do this?

Comment: Yeah, you need an App ID. It's not hard to register one.